# Cookies not accessible when I fetch in Astro frontmatter

Tags: server-side-rendering, cloudflare, astrojs

#### Astro Info

```
Astro                    v4.4.15
Node                     v18.18.0
System                   Windows (x64)
Package Manager          pnpm
Output                   server
Adapter                  @astrojs/cloudflare
Integrations             @astrojs/tailwind
                         @qwikdev/astro
                         astro-compressor
                         @astrojs/react
```

#### Describe the Bug

I have enabled Astro SSR.
This is my astro file

```
---
import Layout from "@layouts/Layout.astro";
import { generateCSRFToken } from "@modules/common";

const csrfToken = await generateCSRFToken();

const res = await fetch(import.meta.env.PUBLIC_DOMAIN + "/api/data", {
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
  },
});
const result = await res.json();
---

<Layout title="Welcome to Astro.">
  <section>
result : {result}
  </section>
</Layout>
```

The generateCSRFToken function will send another fetch request which looks like this

```
import type { APIRoute } from "astro";
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";
import { setCookie } from "@modules/common";

export const GET: APIRoute = async ({ cookies, request }) => {
  const csrfToken = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(36).toString(
    CryptoJS.enc.Base64
  );

  setCookie(cookies, "X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken, false, "/", 1);

  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ csrfToken }), {
    status: 200,
  });
};
```

The issue is that if I try to access the cookie value by using cookies.get in the GET request, I got the value but if I do the cookies.get in the front matter or the middleware.ts, I'm not able to get the value. So, my temporary resort is to move the fetch request to the script tag which solves the issue of not being able to access the cookies values after sending the GET request.

#### Link to Minimal Reproducible Example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9qeh1c?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.astro

After sending a GET request in the frontmatter which sets the cookie value, I want to be able to access the value of the cookie being set previously in the frontmatter.

Comment: "The generateCSRFToken function will send another fetch request" huh? why would you make a http request to the same server you're already running on? that's terribly unperformant an error-prone (network can fail). Just call a normal JS function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I forgot that I could run the server code in the frontmatter where I could just call JS function instead of making another http request. I have edited my index.astro in the stackblitz. Just curious, I wonder why I'm unable to make the http request in the frontmatter? I'm getting Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when I run it locally

Comment: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" usually means that the http response you're getting is HTML, not JSON. (Because the first character of an HTML string is usally `<`)

Answer (score 0):

My current solution to achieve what I wanted (send GET request) in frontmatter.

```
---
import Layout from "@layouts/Layout.astro";
import { GET } from "../api/generateCSRFToken";
import { GET as GET2 } from "../api/data"

const result1 = await GET(Astro);
const { csrfToken } = await result1.json();

Astro.request.headers.set("X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken);
const res2 = await GET2(Astro);

const result = await res2.json();
console.log(result)
---
```